# Script mostra mensagem de sucesso, mas nao atualiza o banco

Tags: php

Por que o banco tá mostrando a mensagem de sucesso, mas não tá atualizando o banco?

```
<?php
$conectar = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root","","usuario_noticias"); 
    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    $login = $_POST["login"];
    $senha = $_POST["senha"];
    $cod = $_POST["codigo"];


    $sql_pesquisa = "SELECT 
                            login_user
                                FROM usuario WHERE login_user='$login' and cod_user = '$cod'";

    $resultado_consulta = mysqli_query ($conectar, $sql_consulta);

    $linhas = mysqli_num_rows ($sql_resultado);

        if($linhas==1){

            echo "<script> alert ('Login já existe. Tente de novo.') </script>";

            echo "<script>location.href = ('altera_exclui_user.php') </script>";
            exit();

        }
        else {
            $sql_altera = "UPDATE usuario  
                                SET
                                    nome_user='$nome',
                                    login_user='$login',
                                    senha_user='$senha'
                                WHERE
                                 cod_user = 'cod'";

            $slq_resultado_alteracao = mysqli_query ($conectar, $sql_altera);

                    if($slq_resultado_alteracao==true){

                        echo"<script> alert ('$nome alterado com sucesso') </script>";
                        echo "<script>location.href = ('altera_exclui_user.php') </script>";
                            exit();
                        }

                    else{
                        echo"<script> alert ('Problemas com o servidor. Tente novamente!') </script>";
                        echo "<script>location.href = ('altera_exclui_user.php') </script>";

                        }                   


        }

?>
```

Comment: O where parece estar errado, não seria assim: `WHERE
                             cod_user = '$cod'"`?

Comment: Como o @RicardoPontual comentou, ele apresenta a mensagem de sucesso porque ela foi concluída com sucesso, o `UPDATE` está sendo realizado no registro onde cod_user é igual a 'cod'

Answer (score 4):

Não está pegando o valor correto do codigo no `WHERE`, precisa mudar para pegar `$cod`, assim:

```
$sql_altera = "UPDATE usuario  
                  SET
                      nome_user='$nome',
                      login_user='$login',
                      senha_user='$senha'
                 WHERE
                      cod_user = '$cod'";
```

Comment: Fiz isso, mas continuou com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Escreve o valor da variável `$sql_altera` na página e veja está tudo correto, se executando direto o comando no banco funciona, se está chegando o valor correto na variável `$cod`. Se o campo `cod_user` for numérico não precisa das aspas simples